# The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, tcp

I just downloaded this project:

https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-2-angular-5-example

explained on this tutorial:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/12/04/basic-crud-angular-and-spring-boot

But when I try to run the server with the recommended command:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

I get the following output:

```
David@HP /cygdrive/d/wamp64/www/external/okta.example.com/server
$ ./mvnw spring-boot:run
/cygdrive/d/wamp64/www/external/okta.example.com/server
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.okta.developer:demo >-----------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ demo >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\wamp64\www\external\okta.example.com\server\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ demo <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ demo ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-07-12 20:35:06.400  INFO 2812 --- [           main] com.okta.developer.demo.DemoApplication  : Starting DemoApplication on HP with PID 2812 (D:\wamp64\www\external\okta.example.com\server\target\classes started by David in D:\wamp64\www\external\okta.example.com\server)
2018-07-12 20:35:06.410  INFO 2812 --- [           main] com.okta.developer.demo.DemoApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-12 20:35:06.499  INFO 2812 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@ae5e109: startup date [Thu Jul 12 20:35:06 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-12 20:35:08.603  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2018-07-12 20:35:09.470  INFO 2812 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29541950] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-12 20:35:10.064  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-07-12 20:35:10.114  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

...

Using generated security password: 4f87a125-b4d8-47c0-9a24-bb5fb3b2a658

2018-07-12 20:35:17.428  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3052460, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@76eee741, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@622ee9f2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@59d663e0, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@a2d3781, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7492ef4f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@77d8457b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1e249f41, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@43e1a956, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7130b0d2, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@384e11db]
2018-07-12 20:35:17.539  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-07-12 20:35:17.558  INFO 2812 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-07-12 20:35:17.558  INFO 2812 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-07-12 20:35:17.558  INFO 2812 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-07-12 20:35:17.660  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-07-12 20:35:17.665  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-07-12 20:35:10.114  INFO 2812 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2018-07-12 20:35:17.684  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-07-12 20:35:17.755 ERROR 2812 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:256) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:198) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at com.okta.developer.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
        ... 20 common frames omitted

2018-07-12 20:35:17.770  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-07-12 20:35:17.815  INFO 2812 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-12 20:35:17.820 ERROR 2812 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2018-07-12 20:35:17.820  INFO 2812 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@ae5e109: startup date [Thu Jul 12 20:35:06 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-12 20:35:17.825  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-07-12 20:35:17.825  INFO 2812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-07-12 20:35:17.835  INFO 2812 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-12 20:35:17.835  INFO 2812 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2018-07-12 20:35:17.850  INFO 2812 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-07-12 20:35:17.860  INFO 2812 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted (TomcatWebServer.java:228)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start (TomcatWebServer.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.okta.developer.demo.DemoApplication.main (DemoApplication.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.171 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-12T20:35:17-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

As you can see, there is one line that says:

```
The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start.
```

Any idea on how to make the server work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered reading the stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says "BindException: Address already in use: bind", you must already be running some application under port 8080. Try to terminate that server and start again, or use a different port for this application, like 8081. If you can't check which app is using port 8080 already, use the following command

```
netstat -anob
```

You can now check and kill the application through task manager, assuming you're on windows.

Answer (score 3):

It says "BindException: Address already in use.
Check below command to see if port is in use:
`lsof -i:8080`
And then kill the process using:
 Kill -9

Alternatively you can use another port.

Answer (score 1):

Use other than 8080 port.
Add  `server.port=port` number, for example `server.port = 8085` in `application.properties` file, from src/main/resources directory.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows CMD you can find the **Process-id** of a running
process on a specific port with:

*netstat /nao | findstr "8080"*

Then you can kill this process with:

*taskkill /pid   **Process-id**  /f*

Comment: This is the best, most concise answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this *port in use* issue with `Spring Boot 5.1.8.RELEASE` which was using `Tomcat 9.0.26`

The project ran perfectly fine in Eclipse STS but would not run on the CLI once built (using Maven). I tried using a whole bunch of different ports to no avail. Same issue every time.

I did 2 things

1) Made sure the Packaging was set to `war` (not jar) - I am using JSP/JSTL for my pages, you might not need to do this yourself.

2) Updated the **Tomcat version to 9.0.27** as suggested in this SO post: [Spring boot 2 embed tomcat 9.0.26 can not load jks file stream closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189855/spring-boot-2-embed-tomcat-9-0-26-can-not-load-jks-file-stream-closed)
It seems there is a bug in the version of Tomcat that was being used - 9.0.26

I was getting the port in use message from Spring Boot but this was a red-herring.

I looked up the Exception trace and it seemed to bomb out during the SSL configuration. A quick google took me to the post mentioned above.

I tried it and it worked first time.

The other answers on here are absolutely correct regarding the port being checked/changed. I just hope this answer might help someone who has checked their port usage like I did.

Answer (score -1):

It says 'Bind Exception', means the port 8080 is already having a connection. 
You can simply get a new free socket, use bind() on the port you are using, The OS will simply pick an unused port. simply create the application.properties file and put server.port=(newport);