# Spring boot 2 embed tomcat 9.0.26 can not load jks file stream closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I try to use SSL on spring boot 2.2.0 with embeded tomcat 9.0.26 but
tomcat can not load JKS file stream closed.

Here is application properties:

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=C:\\Keystore\\mykey.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=cccc 
server.ssl.key-alias=*.mydomain.com
```

> Exception:
>
> org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
>   start embedded Tomcat server
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:215)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at eu.soluma.app.SolumaTdvApplication.main(SolumaTdvApplication.java:34)
>   ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   ~[SolumaTDV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   ~[SolumaTDV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
>   ~[SolumaTDV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
>   ~[SolumaTDV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   standardService.connector.startFailed
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:278)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           ... 18 common frames omitted Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           ... 20 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream closed
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:218)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1124)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1210)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           ... 22 common frames omitted Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:176)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:342)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.security.DigestInputStream.read(DigestInputStream.java:125)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:659)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1472) ~[na:na]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:69)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:217)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           ... 28 common frames omitted

Comment: have you tried putting the path to your keystore in "double quotes" and with single slashes ? e.g. `server.ssl.key-store="C:\Keystore\mykey.jks"`

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the location with `file:`?

Comment: Yes I tried both tips but no luck

Comment: What's the question here, exactly?

Answer (score 25):

It is a regression introduced in Tomcat 9.0.25 that will be fixed in 9.0.27.

Comment: Downgraded to Spring Boot 2.1.8 and it solved the problem.

Comment: Does anyone have more info on this? I had the same issue and I found the exception thrown really vague.

Comment: This seems to be the issue where this regression is tracked.  The issue is now closed. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18505

Comment: Actually, that one applies to files in a jar, not on the local file system.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Pedro. I have the issue with Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE and can confirm that it is resolved by downgrading to 2.1.8.

Comment: Java 12 and from Spring 2.1.9.RELEASE to 2.1.8.RELEASE worked for me too.

Comment: ...who is Pedro?

Answer (score 1):

2.1.10.RELEASE also corrects the problem seen in 2.1.9.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Spring boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE and Java 11 combinations solved the issue for me.