# Spring boot app able launch in eclipse environment but not when run in windows command line with snapshot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, tls1.2

I'm currently trying to implement spring boot app that as `tlsv1.2` supported . Able to launch the spring boot app with eclipse ide , but if i generate snapshot and try executing it , it wont launch

Spring boot snapshot version : `2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`
command ran : `java -jar <somesample-snapshot>`

But ports are not busy or all the **keystore** & **truststore** required are present

this is the config of `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8449
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-store-password: allpassword
    trust-store: classpath:truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: allpassword
    client-auth: need
    enabled: true
    protocol: TLS
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
```

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:263)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:195)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
>   [spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>           at com.ibm.RoAlliesApplication.main(RoAlliesApplication.java:10)
>   [classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [ro-allies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [ro-allies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
>   [ro-allies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
>   [ro-allies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream closed
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:218)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1124)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1210)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           ... 22 common frames omitted Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
>           at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.ensureOpen(InflaterInputStream.java:67)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:142)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
>   ~[ro-allies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at java.security.DigestInputStream.read(DigestInputStream.java:124)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:69)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:217)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar!/:9.0.26]
>           ... 28 common frames omitted
>
> 2019-10-07 23:28:42.800  INFO 3716 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2019-10-07 23:28:42.824  INFO 3716 --- [           main]
>   ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-10-07 23:28:42.828
>   ERROR 3716 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8449 failed to
>   start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be
>   misconfigured.
>
> Action:
>
> Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process
>   that's listening on port 8449, or configure this application to listen
>   on another port.
>
> 2019-10-07 23:28:42.836  INFO 3716 --- [           main]
>   o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down
>   ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58198805/6414086

Answer (score 0):

I have added below tomcat 9.0.30 dependencies and it worked for me.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.30</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.30</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.30</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.30</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.30</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.30</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.30</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like ZipInflaterInputStream as issues in unziping and stack trace is not clear , but the workaround to make it run over command line

jar xf  and then execute

java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher