# Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start - Nothing running on port 8080

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

When trying to run a Spring Boot application I am getting the common error "The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start". I checked and nothing is running on port 8080 nor is port 8080 listening or waiting. I switched to port 8083 and got the same error. This application was running fine yesterday and all of the sudden I started getting this error. As a last ditch effort I did restart my machine in hopes of killing any rogue processes, that did not help.

Any ideas on what else to try?

TIA

Comment: Please add the logs (`catalina.<date>.log`) to your question.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I am running on Windows using VS Code with a bash terminal, so I am not sure a catalina log is being generated?  If it is, I don't know where to find it.  I am adding the console log if that helps.

Comment: Having issues getting the log file attached to the original post, will get it added ASAP.

Comment: Could you check your environment according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51316700/1063509

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi I have already confirmed that port 8080 is not being used.

Comment: @CoryS. could you please provide full start log of your spring boot application?

Comment: I decided to try running on port 4200 and it works.  No idea why port 8080, 8081, 8083 are blocked but at least I am back in business.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue yesterday now my app is run without making any change. Shutdown you PC restart it after sometime it will work. You can clear chase memory also.

It happens with spring-boot.

Comment: I have tried restarting, that did not fix the issue.  Thanks

Comment: I stand corrected... I had tried restarting (not shutting down) my machine and it didn't resolve the issue.  I just shut it down completely and restarted and now the issue is gone.  Too bad I wasted a few hours chasing this one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that restarting my machine wasn't enough... after completly shutting the system down and then restarting it appears the port has been released and the issue is resolved.  Thanks

Comment: If your issue is resolved please accept my answer.